# I need a "don't do it if my class is disabled" kind of CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I currently have the following CSS:

```
a.enabled:hover { background-color: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

Code:

```html
<div><a class="enabled" ......>07</a></div>
<div><a class="enabled" ....... >08</a></div>
<div><a class="disabled" >09</a></div>
<div><a class="enabled" ...... >10</a></div>
<div><a class="enabled" .......>11</a></div>
```

When I hover over an "enabled" link then the background color changes. When I hover over a "disabled" link then nothing happens.

I would like cut down on the size of my page by removing all the class="enabled" text that appears on so many lines (more than 200). Something like this.

After:

```html
<div><a  ........>07</a></div>
<div><a  ....... >08</a></div>
<div><a class="disabled" >09</a></div>
<div><a  ...... >10</a></div>
<div><a  .......>11</a></div>
```

Is there a way I can do this with CSS? I just want the hover not to change the background-color if the link has a "disabled" status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selector you will use is

```
a:not(.disabled):hover { background-color: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

The trade-off is browser compatibility - IE < 9 does not support  `:not()`. As a workaround you can use an override rule with these two rules instead, if you can define a default background color:

```
a, a.disabled:hover { /* Default background and border */ }
a:hover { background-color: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

... or just stick to your existing `.enabled` and `.disabled` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add a css rule for a.disalbe:hover that has the same colour as the default that you have for a

```
a, a.disabled:hover { background-color: red; }
a:hover { background-color: green; }
```

[demo in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/usawav/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: You can group the first and third selectors together.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the css `:not` selector.

```
div a:not(.disabled):hover
```

Comment: I have never seen this before. Is this well supported? Yeah this would be perfect for me.

Comment: I talk about browser support in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

could you just apply a style to all `div a` and then undo it when the `.disabled` class is applied?

Something like

```
a.disabled:hover { background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid transparent; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a.disabled:hover { background-color: red; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

Did you tried this? Or something like this:

```
a:hover { /* disabled-definitions */ }
a.enabled:hover { background-color: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

...and then you only use the enabled class in your HTML